# Is There A Way To Make Theme Files Accept Shortcodes?

Tags: php, theme-development, shortcode

I noticed there are plugins to allow shortcode usage in widgets, and they obviously work on posts/pages, but they don't seem to work when added directly to the theme files.

Is there a way to allow shortcodes to work when added to a theme file?

Answer (score 1):

Try `do_shortcode()`

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to use shortcodes in PHP templates then you need to use this function :

```
do_shortcode()
```

check this out :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/